# Storing file from request stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, audio, stream

I want to create Web API, where, I am uploading audio stream from the client-side and in the nodejs server, I want to save the audio stream as a file an then I wan to upload the file to S3. How Can I save the stream as a file in hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for uploading (audio) files from a client to a node.js server. Once the request is successful, the file can be uploaded to S3. Something like the following:

```
route.post('/upload-audio', (req, res) => {
    const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
    const upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        limits: {
            fileSize: 6000000
        }
    });
    upload.single('track')(req, res, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    // return error
                }

    // upload to S3
```

The [following post](https://medium.com/@richard534/uploading-streaming-audio-using-nodejs-express-mongodb-gridfs-b031a0bcb20f) outlines this quite well.

Comment: Thanks, @wasbeer. I have used multer for receiving a file. but now in this case client is uploading audio stream an audio file as multipart form data.

Comment: @RohanDas You are welcome. Multer handles multipart form data, correct? Is this what you are looking for, or different?

Comment: Let me explain more. On the client-side, I am recording audio using a microphone and I am sending the recorded audio stream to the server. Will Multer work here to saving a file from a stream?

Comment: Multer will help you to handle the audio file stream. It wel set the audio file to `req.file`. You can use `req.file` consequently to upload the audio to S3.